# Why I can not use space after on :before :after content when using unicode

Tags: css, unicode, char, css-content

I just was wondering why in **CSS** when using **unicode** I can not put **space** **after** unicode :

**This is my test :**

```css
div {font-size:50px;}
div:before, div:after {color:green;}
.a:before {content: 'text-before \2022 ';}
.b:before {content: 'text-before • ';}
.c:after {content: ' \2022 text-after';}
.d:after {content: ' • text-after';}
```

```html
<div class="a">A-Hello</div>
<div class="b">B-Hello</div>
<div class="c">C-Hello</div>
<div class="d">D-Hello</div>
```

---

So you will see `B` and `D` using non-unicode is allowed to add space after char. But when using unicode (`A` and `C`) spaces is gone.

```css
.x:before {content: '\2022 ';}
```

```html
<div class="x">Hello</div>
```

So question is : **Why and how to add real space-char (as we press space-bar on keyboard) after uncicode ?** (Without using margin padding)

Comment: One you have used the  escape slash to apply unicode it **stays escaped** so the 'normal' keyboard "space" no longer applies in that string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The space is consumed as part of the escape sequence to prevent other hexadecimal characters from being misinterpreted as part of the escape sequence. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#escaped-characters):

> If a character in the range [0-9a-fA-F] follows the hexadecimal number, the end of the number needs to be made clear. There are two ways to do that:
>
> 1. with a space (or other white space character): "\26 B" ("&B"). In this case, user agents should treat a "CR/LF" pair (U+000D/U+000A) as a single white space character.
> 2. by providing exactly 6 hexadecimal digits: "\000026B" ("&B")

For example, the space helps distinguish the string `'\2022 ff'` from the string `'\2022ff'`, which would mean something entirely different (I'm not even sure it represents an actual character).

To add a space after the special character, add another space character:

```css
.x:before {content: '\2022  ';}
```

```html
<div class="x">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an unicode space `'\00a0'` before or after the dot like so:

```css
div {font-size:50px;}
div:before, div:after {color:green;}
.a:before {content: 'tex-before \2022 \00a0';}
.b:before {content: 'text-before • ';}
.c:after {content: ' \2022 \00a0 text-after';}
.d:after {content: ' • text-after';}
```

```html
<div class="a">A-Hello</div>
<div class="b">B-Hello</div>
<div class="c">C-Hello</div>
<div class="d">D-Hello</div>
```